# Get list of available functions from exprtk::symbol_table

Tags: c++, exprtk

I would like to query all available function names from a symbol_table. I can see that symbol_table has methods for getting variables, vectors, and stringvars (i.e. `symbol_table::get_variable_list`). However, I don't see a corresponding `symbol_table::get_function_list`. Is there some other way that I can get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exprtk::symbol_table` now supports obtaining the names of all registered user defined functions.

```
template <typename T>
struct myfunc final : public exprtk::ifunction<T>
{
   using exprtk::ifunction<T>::operator();

   myfunc()
   : exprtk::ifunction<T>(2)
   { exprtk::disable_has_side_effects(*this); }

   inline T operator()(const T& v1, const T& v2)
   {
      return T(1) + (v1 * v2) / T(3);
   }
};

template <typename T>
inline T myotherfunc(T v0, T v1, T v2)
{
   return std::abs(v0 - v1) * v2;
}
 .
 .
 .
using symbol_table_t = exprtk::symbol_table<T>;
using expression_t   = exprtk::expression<T>;
using parser_t       = exprtk::parser<T>;

symbol_table_t symbol_table;

myfunc<T> mf;

symbol_table.add_function("f1",[](T v0) -> T { return v0;});
symbol_table.add_function("f2",[](T v0, T v1) -> T{ return v0 / v1;});

symbol_table.add_function("myfunc"   , mf         );
symbol_table.add_function("otherfunc", myotherfunc);

std::vector<std::string> function_list;

symbol_table.get_function_list(function_list);

for (const auto& func : function_list)
{
   printf("function: %s\n",func.c_str());
}
```

**Note:** Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the awesome library.